# Folder upload without drag-and-drop

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

How would one go about implementing folder uploading without using drag-and-drop? I'm looking to be able to select folders the same way one would select files.

Also, what are the upper-bounds of the number of files and folder depth?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but the solution is a bit awkward, which is why Fine Uploader doesn't natively support this.  A file input element can either allow you to select folders OR files, not both simultaneously.  So, if you want your users to choose, you will need to either provide a separate file input specifically for selecting folders, or maintain one file input element that is modified on-the-fly once the user's intentions are known.

Fine Uploader will likely provide support for selecting folders via the chooser dialog in the future as part of [case #819](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/819).  In the meantime, if you want to provide the ability to allow your users to select folders via the chooser dialog, you will need to provide an alternate file input element exclusively for folders, and then send the selected files in the folder to Fine Uploader via Fine Uploader's `addFiles` API method.

Here's an example:

```
<input type="file" id="directoryFileInput" webkitdirectory>
<div id="myFineUploaderContainer"></div>

$('#myFineUploaderContainer').fineUploader({
    request: {
        endpoint: 'my/endpoint'
    }
});

$('#directoryFileInput').change(function() {
    var fileList = this.files;

    $('#myFineUploaderContainer').fineUploader('addFiles', fileList);
});
```

Of course, you may want to also style this specific file input.  Once Fine Uploader case #819 is complete, you will be able to ask Fine Uploader to style and track any additional file inputs for you.  Until then, if this is important to you, you will need to make any additional file input element opaque and wrap it in a styled div.